# How to get day,month,year from String date?

Tags: java, android

I have a date on String, like this:

`String date="25.07.2007";`

And I want to divide it to:

```
String day;
String month;
String year;
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `.split(".");` works

Comment: @3kings can you please detail?

Comment: "Best" is relative. Do you want a Date object that you can reformat, or do you just want the strings?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way to split a string in Java is to use .split("regex") which splits a string according to the pattern provided, returning a String array.

```
String [] dateParts = date.split(".");
String day = dateParts[0];
String month = dateParts[1];
String year = dateParts[2];
```

To get current date:
You can also change the format of the date by changing the values passed to SimpleDateFormat. Don't forget the imports.

```
  DateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
  Date date = new Date();
```

Comment: It would be `[0]` , `[1]` , `[2]` please do fix that

Comment: Thanks! and by the way, I want to get the current date and compare it to to the day, month and year we've wrote above. How can I get the current date?

Comment: @olash12345 see edited answer.. For any more help start new question thread.

Comment: @olash12345 also if I answered your question, please accept my answer

Comment: Using standard date classes for the job is a good idea. Using the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` is poor one. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36294846/5772882).

Answer (score 7):

## java.time

The modern way is to use the [Android version](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) of the [back-port](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) of the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

First, parse the input string into a date-time object. The `LocalDate` class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
String input = "25.07.2007";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM.dd.yyyy" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , formatter );
```

Now you can ask the [`LocalDate`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalDate.html) for its values.

```
int year = localDate.getYear();
int month = localDate.getMonthValue();
int dayOfMonth = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
```

You can use the handy [`Month`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/Month.html) enum to localize the name of the month.

```
String monthName = localDate.getMonth().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

Comment: Note: this is only available since Android 8.0 (API 26)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
String dateArr[] = date.split(".");
String day = dateArr[0];
String month = dateArr[1];
String year = dateArr[2];
```

**or**

```
String day = date.substring(0,2);
String month = date.substring(3,5);
String year = date.substring(6,10);
```

To get the current date...

```
Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

To get day, month and year from current date..

```
int day = currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Month starts at 0 here...

Comment: Thanks! and by the way, I want to get the current date and compare it to to the day, month and year we've wrote above. How can I get the current date?

Comment: What do you mean in "Month starts ar 0 here"? The count of the monthes starts from 0 and ends in 11?

Answer (score 0):

Note:  `date.split(".")` will not work. Split methods takes regex as parameter. For regex "." means any character. Instead we have to pass `"\\."` as parameter.

```
String [] dateParts = date.split("\\.");
String day = dateParts[0];
String month = dateParts[1];
String year = dateParts[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DateTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws ParseException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String starDate = "7/12/1995 12:00:00 AM";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String newDateStr = simpleDateFormat.format(simpleDateFormat.parse(starDate));
        String str[] = newDateStr.split("/");
        String month = str[1];
        String year = str[2];
    }

}
```

Comment: Using standard date classes for the job is a good idea. Using the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` is poor one. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36294846/5772882).